# How to dismiss context menu (UIContextMenu) programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, contextmenu

I have an iOS app. Some `UIViewControllers` have automatically updated content, it means that app can get update (simple JSON) any time  (but no more often than about 1 time in half an hour). View controllers have `UICollectionView` with `UIContextMenu` for iOS >= 13.0.

Some times arises a situation when the user has called the context menu, but the content of cell and its menu are no longer relevant. `UICollectionView` already reloaded (with resorting cells), but context menu still shown.
I know when the update happens in my app and I want to dismiss open menu in this moment.
So my question is - how to dismiss context menu programmatically?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi, have you then found a solution for dismissing the context menu? From iOS 14+ `collectionView.contextMenuInteraction.dismissMenu()` can be used and works fine, however it doesn't seem to work when running on Mac Catalyst.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Please try this solution.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willPerformPreviewActionForMenuWith configuration: UIContextMenuConfiguration, animator: UIContextMenuInteractionCommitAnimating) {
        animator.preferredCommitStyle = .dismiss 
    }
```

Comment: thanks for help, but I can't see any way to run this without user interaction